# House packing in Texas with no Air conditioner

Tags: personal-care, temperature, eyesight

I am trying to figure out the best way of keeping sweat out of my eyes. I'm spending more time wiping my face because my eyes are burning than getting anything actually packed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Great question, but I believe it has been asked already.